# cakePHP- SQL- adding values from different tables in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I am working on a project which requires me to do some querying which I m having a bit of trouble since my sql is a little rusty. There are 3 tables involved in the query :

```
donors
donations
donation_methods
```

I need to run a valid sql statement logically similar to this with the correct syntax :

```
SELECT  `tel_no` 
  FROM  `donors` as `dnr` 
        LEFT JOIN  `donations` as `dn` 
                   ON  `dnr`.id =  `dn`.donor_id
        LEFT JOIN  `donation_method` as `dm` 
                   ON `dn`.donation_method_id = `dm`.id
  WHERE `dn`.created`+`dm`.recovery_time >= NOW() // here is the problem
```

Im not entirely sure on how to do it! Any help? Also if this can be done using cake's method (find,etc), in conjunction with the 'conditions' array, that would be great!
 Thanks

**[EDIT]**
Recovery time is of INT type, whilst created is of type datetime

Comment: What are the column types of `created` and `recovery_time`?

Comment: Not sure about your data type by correct syntax is  WHERE `dn`.`created`+`dm`.`recovery_time`

Comment: @RobM. I editted my question!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I don't quite understand what you mean! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`DATE_ADD` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) for this

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(dn.created, INTERVAL dn.recovery_time YEAR) >= NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! and wasn't aware of this my_sql method! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

change

```
WHERE `dn`.created`+`dm`.recovery_time >= NOW()
          ^ missing `
```

to

```
WHERE `dn`.`created`+`dm`.`recovery_time` >= NOW()
```